# How do I bring data from one SQL table and column into the same column depedent on specific contraints?

Tags: sql

For example the data I want to bring over resides in Table1, in column `example_Date`. The application in question uses this column to house data for multiple data field ID's.

Table1:

```
Table ID  Field ID  Obj ID  Obj Inv  example_Date
--------------------------------------------------
1         2         1       3        01/01/1996
1         4         1       3        01/02/1996
1         6         1       3        01/01/1996
1         2         2       4        01/05/1996
1         4         2       4        01/01/1997
1         6         2       4        10/01/1998
```

Then let's say I want to take the data in example_date that has a Field ID of 2 and copy it over to anything in the same table that has the following constraints:

1. Obj ID = Obj ID
2. Obj Inv = Obj Inv
3. Field ID = 6

And the result would look like the below ( * = the updated data)

Table1:

```
Table ID  Field ID  Obj ID  Obj Inv  example_Date
-------------------------------------------------
1         2         1       3        01/01/1996
1         4         1       3        01/02/1996
1         6         1       3       *01/01/1996
1         2         2       4        01/05/1996
1         4         2       4        01/01/1997
1         6         2       4       *01/05/1996
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Example 1 (does not work):

```
UPDATE ValInvData
SET ValStr = ValStr
WHERE ValInvData.FieldId = 11061
  AND ValInvData.ObjID = ValInvData.ObjId
  AND ValInvData.ObjInv = ValInvData.ObjInv
  AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11051
  AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11061
  AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11062
  AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11055
  AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11228
  AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11230
  AND ValInvData.FieldId != 14676;
```

Example 2 (does not work):

```
UPDATE ValInvData
SET ValStr = (SELECT ValStr
              FROM ValInvData
              WHERE Valdata.FieldId = 11061
                AND ObjData.ObjID = ValData.ObjId
                AND ValInvData.ObjInv = ValInvData.ObjInv
                AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11051
                AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11061
                AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11062
                AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11055
                AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11228
                AND ValInvData.FieldId != 11230
                AND ValInvData.FieldId != 14676);
```

Final Solution

```
update ValInvData
set ValStr = coalesce(
    (
        select min(ValStr) -- to guarantee only one value returned,
                                 -- possibly better to error??
        from ValInvData as vid
        where vid.ObjId = ValInvData.ObjId and vid.ObjInv = ValInvData.ObjInv and vid.FieldId = 11061
    ),
    ValInvData.ValStr) -- could also use exists subquery to ensure matching row is available
where FieldId = 11229;
```

Comment: Please include your current attempt and explain what issue you are having. Your sample data and desired results are identical....?

Comment: Just fixed it up a bit. Also I have done very similar to the above before, but it has always been from either a different table, or a different coloumn.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you've done before, so that we can help you apply similar logic in this case.

Comment: Yeah sorry was having issues with the comment formating. I put the last attempts I made above in the post. The biggest issue I am having, is I basically need to set an argument before I even begin my SET statement. But I do not know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update ValInvData
set example_date = coalesce(
    (
        select min(example_date) -- to guarantee only one value returned,
                                 -- possibly better to error??
        from ValInvData as vid
        where vid.ObjId = ValInvData.ObjId and vid.ObjInv = ValInvData.ObjInv
            and vid.FieldId = 2
    ),
    example_date) -- could also use exists subquery to ensure matching row is available
where FieldId = 6;
```

Comment: This is very interesting, thank you very much for this.  Will be testing it out as soon as I get a chance and will let you know how it goes. This is the first time I have seen the coalesce function, and am currently reading up on it. Will update ASAP!

Comment: The `coalesce()` isn't really critical to what you wanted to accomplish. It's just that if you went to update a row where the lookup failed then I presume you wouldn't want to eradicate the data that was already there. If this doesn't apply to your scenario then you can ignore or work around it differently.

Comment: Thanks for this again, have been testing a few things for the past few hours and am still trying other solutions. At the moment, the above seems to work, however my data is not actually being moved. I have added my current code to the post above, as well as a secondary script I have tried. Both show succesful. The results show that 362 lines were affected, but I can see that they actually where not updated. I think my issue is that because this is a date field, I need to set a data type with CAST. Not sure if this is right or wrong but it is what I have been trying now for the past few hours.

Comment: The data type for this column is NVARCHAR.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, no triggers are set on this table

Comment: @Chester I don't think I understand why you're referring to two different field ids in your scripts.

Comment: Hm sorry, I am not sure which line/script your referencing. Could you let me know please when you get a chance

Comment: I am an idiot, that's why. I just noticed exactly what your talking about. About to test this out again. -Update It works!  Thank you so much for your help on this!

Comment: Ok, I don't really know the role of 2 and 6 from the original. That earlier comment may have been a misunderstanding too.

Comment: I see what you ment. I just noticed I was referencing the wrong ID number in my current scripts. Ie, from the above originally I was looking to view data from 11061, I mistyped and put in 11601. After changing this it worked. I will be updating the final code in the above. Also I used 6 and 2 as I thought it would be easier to understand for a short hand explanation originally. 6 and 2 do not actually exist, 11061 and 11229 do.